# Problem in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I know how to create tables in SQL server 2005. However due to system problems I reinstalled SQL Server 2005. After that I select the option like this:

*Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005 > SQL Server Management Studio Express*

My problem is that SQL Server Management Studio Express does not exist.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Dupe. You have already asked this question today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396273/sql-server-2005

Comment: Took me a while to find, but i knew i'd seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

MSSQL 2005 Express does not come with MSSQL Management Studio Express, that is a separate (but free) download:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c243a5ae-4bd1-4e3d-94b8-5a0f62bf7796&DisplayLang=en

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not correctly install SQL Server.

You will need to remove that completely and then reinstall correctly.

Comment: yes ratty is right, you have not intsalled correct. Reinstall it and when you do it check for the advanced setting.